# How to show the sign column to the right side of the line number column?

Tags: line-numbers, signs

I want Vim's sign column displayed to the *right* side of the line number column, I have it by default on the *left*.

Here is a screenshot showing the sign column enabled and showing a `+` to indicate a line added (I use the **vim-gitgutter** plugin)

[image: Original]

Here's what I am after (photoshopped):

[image: Desired]

(how) Can this be done?

Comment: This is not possible

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Christian in his comment, this is unfortunately impossible.
However, from [patch 8.1.1564](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/394c5d8870b15150fc91a4c058dc571fd5eaa97e), there's an option that could solve this problem.

We can merge the `signcolumn` and the line numbers.

```
:set signcolumn=number
```

From the help ([`:h 'signcolumn'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27signcolumn%27)):

> ```
> 'signcolumn' 'scl'    string  (default "auto")
>      {not available when compiled without the |+signs| feature}
>      Whether or not to draw the signcolumn. Valid values are:
>          "auto"       only when there is a sign to display
>          "no"         never
>          "yes"        always
>          "number"     display signs in the 'number' column. If the number
>                       column is not present, then behaves like "auto".
> ```

This is what it could look like:

[image: :signlumn=number]